Img src not loading on page from local files
So, I am trying to add an imgsrc (logo) over a  background to be later modified in ****.js for graphical/animation purposes.  I am using vsc with the live server extension to see live progress(locally; changing the file-pathing on live ftp later). I have an image folder for all the images on the site which I am pulling the source from (link rel). The images are not appearing/rendering on the canvas/page . How can I get this image to render?;
i.e. - I have removed the imgsrc from canvas to make the logo display for now.  I am just trying to get the image to load at the moment. So, the overall question I have is this; Are you not able to have links/images within , or I do I need to use ****.js to make it work? {answered; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas}
Tl;dr - Essentially I would like to alter an image with the canvas element and animate the image; giving an update to a logo.

<canvas>
</canvas>
<img src="C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/webpageproject/workspace/images/origdllogox1.png">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="pages\about.html">about</li></a>
                <li><a href="pages\contact.html">contact</li></a>
                <li><a href="pages\members.html">members</li></a
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

<!--navbarheading end-->



canvas  {
    image-resolution: 1080p;
    background: indigo;
    height: 100px;
    width: 1920px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

canvas::after   {
    content: '';
    display:contents;
}

header  {
    background:fixed;
}

header::after   {
    content: '';
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}

.nav {
    display: contents;
}

nav ul  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    color:darkolivegreen;
    float: right;
}

nav li  {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}



I am unclear what you are trying to do with having an img element as a child of a canvas element. That will be rendered only if Javascript is switched off or on a browser that does not support canvas. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas?mdrv=b83c1k

I was trying to get the image to load over a canvas without using java. Research has told me <canvas> is used mainly with APIs in this way and it's overkill for this task as I am not trying to create animations currently. The image will not load OUTSIDE  of canvas either (even on a blank page). I tried putting the image in the same folder (/index/) and the image will still not load. I'm sure it's something simple I missed.

I suspect you have misunderstood how canvas works - and also by 'without using Java' do you mean 'without using Javascript'? You can't get an image onto a canvas without using JS in the way you are thinking. But the fundamental question is - why can't the image be used in the normal way, either as the src of an img element or as a background image to another element. I am still not clear exactly what you want to do, but is the problem that you are trying to load a local image from a website?

You have done some edits but you are still putting the img element within the canvas element which won't show anything (unless you have JS switched off or are using a very old browser which doesn't support canvas). Please have a good read of how canvas works if you are convinced you need to use canvas - I'm not convinced I think a normal img or background-image would suffice. Is there a reason you need canvas?

I have explained this thoroughly. It is to make changes in javascript after I get the image to load over a canvas with background. please read the description again.

I repeat, you can't get an image to load over a canvas by putting it as a child of the canvas.

Which is why my post states it has been removed as a child element on the initial post. This is not helpful in any way. Thank you Ahmad for contributing helpful information.

Please therefore show the relevant code, forget putting an img as a child of a canvas, and indeed I suggest forgetting canvas altogether and show what you have tried using an img element or a background-image, describe what debugging you have done and include a minimal reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

answer this for me if you would. can you animate a .png image within canvas. If so, how.  And yes i know what mdn says about the  element. I have not applied any javascript as I am studying and am not practiced in java(script).

What sort of animation are you looking for?

You can’t load a local file like that. This reference might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Images_in_HTML

I was trying to see how to digitize a logo in the background. I wasn't planning on doing this until later. That's why I left the canvas at the top and put the logo and navbar below it. it's incomplete. still updating/writing.

yes, the error was backslashes instead of forward slashes in the file path. \\ vs /// syntax, syntax, syntax. an easy mistake to make when you copy/paste a file path.

would you like to insert another condescending, insulting comment without any guidance or answer? in no way constructive criticism. definitely criticism though.

this is reference you should have linked hayworth:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images

try copy and paste the image in the same file of index.html for example:
<canvas><img src="origdllogox1.png"></canvas>

or try to use javascript
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const background = new Image();
background.onload = () => { };
background.src = 'origdllogox1.png';
function Animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1920px, 100);
  ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 1920px, 100);

  requestAnimationFrame(Animate);
}
Animate();


thanks for your insight ahmad. very helpful. I need to do some reading up on javascript.

    <canvas>
        <script>
            const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            const background = new Image();
            background.onload = () => { };
            background.src = '/workspace/images/origdllogox1.png';
            function Animate(imgbg) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1920, 100);
            ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 1920, 100);
        
            requestAnimationFrame(Animate);
            }
            Animate(canvas);
        </script>
    </canvas><br>

-now able to draw the image over canvas. Further alternations to the image to be made in javascript.

---Answered by Ahmad Arabati---
